# activityResultLaunch.launch(intent) no llama a onActivityResult()

Tags: android-studio, firebase, onactivityresult

Tengo un breakpoint en el método onActivityResult() y al ejecutar activityResultLaunch.launch(intent) no llega a este método.
Lo que intento hacer es el login de Firebase con una cuenta de google.

Aquí está el código que se ejecuta al pulsar al botón de SignIn con cuenta de Google:

```
 private void googleLogin(){

        GoogleSignInOptions googleConf = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        GoogleSignInClient googleClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleConf);
        googleClient.signOut();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        setResult(GOOGLE_SIGN_IN, intent);
        intent.setFlags(0);
        activityResultLaunch.launch(intent);
    }
```

Y aquí el método que no llega a ser ejecutado:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLaunch = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
                        // Correct
                        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.getData());

                    try {
                        GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult();

                        if (account != null) {
                            Task<AuthResult> it = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null));

                            if (it.isSuccessful()) {
                                //INICIA SESIÓN
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {
                                showAlert();
                            }
                        } else {
                            showAlert();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        showAlert();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Error
                    showAlert();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, **el principal problema por el cual no se llama `onActivityResult()` es porque no tienes configurada una credencial "OAuth 2.0 Client ID" para realizar la petición.**

Ve a Google Cloud Console en API & Services https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/

**Debes configurar una credencial "OAuth 2.0 Client ID" definiendo el SHA-1 del certificado con el cual firmaste tu aplicación, esto para poder tener permisos para realizar la petición a la API.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si estás subiendo directamente tu aplicación desde `Android Studio`, es importante obtengas el `SHA-1` de tu certificado de desarrollo `debug.keystore` que generalmente se encuentra dentro del directorio `C:\Users\Usuario\.android`